# Facebook Connect Login

Tags: facebook

I have facebook login working on my website.

But when users log in, the button just stays the same, i want it to change to the user's image and name.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user is logged in just make a request to "/me?fields=name,picture", using that data modify the dom and replace the button with the name and picture of the user.

Try this query with the [Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?fields=name,picture).